# How do I verify/assert the html below in nightwatch js?

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I have a html class

```
<a class="mobile-nav-btn" href="/news-mobile"><img src="img/news.svg" role="presentation"><span>Resources</span></a>
```

I am trying to click, then assert or verify the above is present .

```
.click('a[class="mobile-nav-btn"][href="/news-mobile"]')
.waitForElementVisible('body', 3000)
.url(function(response){
      console.log('the url is', response.value);
      this.assert.urlContains(response.value, 'news-mobile')
})
```

The above click failed because my url does not change. I can see that from my console. And after a successful click. The class turn to `mobile-nav-btn active` . Below is how I attempt to verify that. It also failed

```
.verify.elementPresent('a[class="mobile-nav-btn active"][href="news-mobile"]')
```

How do I achieved those? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What should work for you

change

```
.click('a[class="mobile-nav-btn"][href="/news-mobile"]')
.waitForElementVisible('body', 3000)
.url(function(response){
      console.log('the url is', response.value);
      this.assert.urlContains(response.value, 'news-mobile')
})
```

to

```
.click('a.mobile-nav-btn[href="/news-mobile"]')
.waitForElementVisible('body', 3000)
.url(function(response){
     this.assert.urlContains(response.value, 'news-mobile')
})
```

And

```
.verify.elementPresent('a[class="mobile-nav-btn active"][href="news-mobile"]')
```

to

```
.assert.cssClassPresent('a.mobile-nav-btn[href="/news-mobile"]','active')
```

Your test failed because you are using the selectors wrong.